# Number of ways in which letters of the word ENGINEER can be arranged so that no two alike letters are together

Tags: combinatorics

Number of ways in which letters of the word ENGINEER can be arranged so that no two alike letters are together is ________

My solution is as follows:

As per the figure number Es=3;G=1;I=1;Ns=2 and R=1, total word is 8

[image]

Number of arrangement of the word "ENGINEER" is $3360$ where $\frac{{8!}}{{3!.2!}} = 3360$

Now let's take the case that our focus is on E and neglect N initially.

Remove Case of the type EE,E,G,I,N,N,R is $\frac{{7!}}{{2!}} = 2520$

Now add cases when EEE,G,I,N,N,R is $\frac{{6!}}{{2!}} = 360$

Hence the number of ways Es are segregated is $3360-2520+360=1200$. There are number of cases when E are segregated. Now do we segregate N also?

Comment: Segregate N's as you go through EE+E case, and do the same for EEE case.

Comment: For EE+E case, from 2520 arrangements, subtract the number 6! of arrangements of EE, E, G, I, NN, R.

Comment: NENGEIRE, satisfy the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrangements with $E's$ placed apart in gaps$\;(-)\;$ [$N's$ may be together or separate]

eg $-N-G-I-N-R-\;\; :\;\; \binom63\times \frac{5!}{2!} = 1200$

Subtract arrangements with the two $N's$ bunched  as a super **N**:$\;\binom53\times 4! = 240$

Answer: $1200-240 = 960$

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this problem with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word ENGINEER is
$$\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{2}3!$$
since we can choose three of the eight positions for the Es, two of the remaining five positions for the Ns, then arrange the three distinct letters G, I, R in the remaining three positions.  From these arrangements, we must subtract those in which a pair of identical letters are adjacent.

*A pair of adjacent identical letters*:  There are two possibilities, a pair of Es is adjacent or a pair of Ns is adjacent.

A pair of Es is adjacent:  We have seven objects to arrange: EE, E, N, N, G, I, R.  Choose two of the seven positions for the Ns, then arrange the five distinct objects EE, E, G, I, R in the remaining positions, which can be done in $$\binom{7}{2}5!$$ ways.

A pair of Ns is adjacent:  We have seven objects to arrange:  E, E, E, NN, G, I, R.  Choose three of the seven positions for the Es, then arrange the four distinct objects NN, G, I, R in the remaining four positions, which can be done in $$\binom{7}{3}4!$$ ways.

*Two pairs of adjacent identical letters*:  There are again two possibilities, either there are two pairs of adjacent Es, in which case all three Es are consecutive, or there is a pair of adjacent Es and a pair of adjacent Ns.

Two pairs of adjacent Es:  We have six objects to arrange: EEE, N, N, G, I, R.  Choose two of the six positions for the Ns, then arrange the four distinct objects EEE, G, I, R in the remaining four positions, which can be done in $$\binom{6}{2}4!$$ ways.

A pair of adjacent Es and a pair of adjacent Ns:  We have six objects to arrange: EE, E, NN, G, I, R.  Since the six objects are distinct, they can be arranged in $$6!$$ ways.

*Three pairs of adjacent identical letters*:  The only way for this to occur is if there are two pairs of adjacent Es and a pair of adjacent Ns.  We have five objects to arrange:  EEE, NN, G, I, R.  Since the five objects are distinct, they can be arranged in $5!$ ways.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word ENGINEER in which no two adjacent letters are identical is
$$\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{2}3! - \binom{7}{2}5! - \binom{7}{3}4! + \binom{6}{2}4! + 6! - 5!$$

Answer (score 2):

To construct the words where no two same characters adjacent ,we use *[Smirnov words](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/joc/2020/0011/0003/JOC-2020-0011-0003-a001.pdf)*

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over an $n$-ary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{nz}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\
\end{align*}

> Here we consider an alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{E,G,I,N,R\}$ with $n=5$ letters. Using $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series we calculate
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{green}{[E^3GIRN^2]\left(1-\sum_{a\in\mathcal{V}}\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^{-1}}\\\
> &\qquad=[E^3GIRN^2]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{a\in\mathcal{V}}\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^j\\\
> &\qquad=[E^3GIRN^2]\sum_{j=5}^{8}\left(\sum_{a\in\mathcal{V}}\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^j\\\
> &\qquad=[E^3GIRN^2]\sum_{j=5}^{8}\left(G+E\left(1-E+E^2\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.+I+R+N(1-N)\right)^j\\\
> &\qquad=-120+1080-3360+3360\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\qquad=960}
> \end{align*}

*[CALCULATION OF EXPANSION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+%28R%5E1K%5E1G%5E1T%5E3N%5E2%29+in+%28%28G%29%2B%28T-T%5E2%2BT%5E3+%29%2B%28R%29%2B%28K%29%2B%28N-N%5E2%29%29%5E8)*